# Triggering editing mode for a form

Tags: c#, form, constructor

I think that my code isn't perfect and I need a help to understand how to optimize it.

In my application I have a main form and several forms for data editing. 
The user can:

- Add a new item
- Edit the selected item
- Delete the selected item
- Duplicate an item with a new name

You can see an example of my code below. I think that the approach to trigger editing mode isn't good.

An alternative way is to create a new form without parameters and then run methods `AddItem()`, `EditItem()`, etc., but I don't think that's a good idea either.

Editor modes:

```
public enum EditMode { Add, Edit, Delete, Copy };
```

Main form has several buttons:

```
    private void AddItemBarButton_ItemClick(object sender, ItemClickEventArgs e)
    {
        ItemForm IF = new ItemForm(EditMode.Add);
        IF.ShowDialog();
        IF.Dispose(); 
    }

    private void EditItemBarButton_ItemClick(object sender, ItemClickEventArgs e)
    {
        if (ActiveItem != null)
        {
            ItemForm IF = new ItemForm(EditMode.Edit, ActiveItem);
            MIF.ShowDialog();
            MIF.Dispose();
        }
    }

    private void DeleteItemBarButton_ItemClick(object sender, ItemClickEventArgs e)
    {
        if (ActiveItem != null)
        {
            ItemForm IF = new ItemForm(EditMode.Delete, ActiveItem);
            MIF.Dispose();
        }
    }

    private void CopyItemBarButton_ItemClick(object sender, ItemClickEventArgs e)
    {
        if (ActiveItem != null)
        {
            ItemForm IF = new ItemForm(EditMode.Delete, ActiveItem, "somenewname");
            MIF.Dispose();
        }
    }
```

Editor form:

```
    private Item T = null;
    private EditMode Mode;

    private ItemForm()
    {
        InitializeComponent();    
    }

    public ItemForm(EditMode mode) : this()  
    {
        Mode = mode;
        switch (Mode)
        {
            case EditMode.Add:
                T = new Item();
                T.Sort_Order = DateTime.Now;
                break;
        }
    }

    public ItemForm(EditMode mode, Item item) : this()
    {
        Mode = mode;
        T = item;
        switch (Mode)
        {
            case EditMode.Edit:
                NameEdit.Text = T.Name;
                CountEdit.Text = T.Countnum.ToString();
                break;

            case EditMode.Delete:
                cDB.Item.DeleteOnSubmit(T);
                cDB.SubmitChanges();
                break;
        }
    }

    public ItemForm(EditMode mode, Item item, string new_name) : this()
    {
        Mode = mode;
        switch (Mode)
        {
            case EditMode.Copy:
                T = new Item();
                T.Name = new_name;
                T.Countnum = item.Countnum;
                T.Sort_Order = item.Sort_Order;
                cDB.Item.InsertOnSubmit(T);
                cDB.SubmitChanges();
                break;
        }
    }

    private void OKButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
            T.Name = NameEdit.Text;
            T.Countnum = Convert.ToInt(CountEdit.Text);

            if (Mode == EditMode.Add) cDB.Item.InsertOnSubmit(T);
            cDB.SubmitChanges();

            this.Close();
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 6):

A small note on naming:

Being new to your code base, I have no idea what `MIF` represents and worse, `IF` looks a lot like `if` and it confuses my eyes. As a rule of thumb, don't abbreviate names. Spell them out so that the maintainer coming behind you understands what everything is.

Answer (score 5):

Your constructors don't handle all possible situations. What if I call `public ItemForm(EditMode mode)` with mode set to `Edit`? When you're overloading constructors, you have to reduce it to one constructor where you handle everything, if this is possible of course.

Small example with a regular method:

```
public int Add(int a, int b)
{
    return a + b;
}

public int Add(int a, int b, int c)
{
    return a + b + c;
}
```

The above is not incorrect, but it should be done like following code:

```
public int Add(int a, int b)
{
    return Add(a, b, 0);
}

public int Add(int a, int b, int c)
{
    return a + b + c;
}
```

As you can see, all the logic is kept in one place. This can also be applied to your code:

```
public ItemForm(EditMode mode) : this(mode, new Item(), "")  
{
}

public ItemForm(EditMode mode, Item item) : this(mode, item, "")
{
}

public ItemForm(EditMode mode, Item item, string new_name) : this()
{
    Mode = mode;

    switch (Mode)
    {
        case EditMode.Add:
            T = item;
            T.Sort_Order = DateTime.Now;
            break;
        case EditMode.Edit:
            T = item;
            NameEdit.Text = T.Name;
            CountEdit.Text = T.Countnum.ToString();
            break;
        case EditMode.Delete:
            cDB.Item.DeleteOnSubmit(T);
            cDB.SubmitChanges();
            break;
        case EditMode.Copy:
            T = new Item();
            T.Name = new_name;
            T.Countnum = item.Countnum;
            T.Sort_Order = item.Sort_Order;
            cDB.Item.InsertOnSubmit(T);
            cDB.SubmitChanges();
            break;
    }
}
```

As you can see everything is handled in the constructor with *all* possible parameters. The other ones just call this one with the right parameters and the necessary action is performed.

Now you only have to handle situations correctly. If I pass `EditMode.Edit` and the item is ***null*** you'll get a `NullReferenceException`. This was also the case with your code though.

**Update: (tip from Morten Christiansen)**

When dealing with lots of code in a switch statement, you can extract that logic into a method and call that method from the case. Example:

```
case EditMode.Copy: CopyItem(item, new_name); break;

public void CopyItem(Item item, string newName)
{
    T = new Item();
    T.Name = newName;
    T.Countnum = item.Countnum;
    T.Sort_Order = item.Sort_Order;
    cDB.Item.InsertOnSubmit(T);
    cDB.SubmitChanges();
}
```

Comment: This kind of code (one switch with a lot of logic) can quickly become very hard to read and I prefer to refactor the content of each case out into a method. Something like this: `case EditMode.Add: AddItem(); break;`.

Comment: @MortenChristiansen Good point, I mentioned it in my answer.

Comment: But what are the advantages comparing to different constructors? Number of constructors will be equal to number of different methods (add, edit, ...).

Comment: I'm not saying this method of working is the best and I wouldn't write this kind of code. This is just a 'better' way when working with multiple constructors.

Answer (score 2):

Debugging the following code to delete an item will lead to digging into `ItemForm` class, because it is a confusing call.

```
if (ActiveItem != null)
{
    ItemForm IF = new ItemForm(EditMode.Delete, ActiveItem);
    MIF.Dispose();
}
```

A better idea would be to add a static method to `ItemForm` like

```
public static void DeleteItem(Item item)
{
    if (item == null){ return; }
    using(ItemForm IF = new ItemForm(EditMode.Delete, item)){}
}
```

this will change you calling code to

```
ItemForm.DeleteItem(ActiveItem);
```

an it is clear what is going on.

Basically, a constructor is for constructing the object. So this approach isn't the best either, but it is at least better.